# Django: how to upload file

Tags: python, django, file-upload, upload

I want to create upload form in site.com/upload/, but did not succeed ):
What should I do?

**settings.py** file

```
"""
Django settings for django_khodro project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'qsypi4#@kw@k-v2z&d70lw9eufbit%axpjkr$(0o(%0&&ovi3g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_khodroha',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_khodro.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_khodro.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

**app/views.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def upload(request):
    return render(request, 'main/uploadform.html')
```

**app/templates/main/uploadform.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="jupload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/urls.py** file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from main_khodroha import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='uploadform'),
]
```

Please tell me the easiest way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a read on [Django documentation: File uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/). It is a bit lengthy to post any code in here, but it has got excellent examples which suit right in your case. They mention in detail how to build your **form** and your **view** as well as how to handle the posted file, all of that in a single official document.